# theorem 10.14 Browder Mathematical Analysis

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

From Mathematical Analysis Andrew Browder

[image]

[image]

If $g$,$h$ not comparable,and $\nu_g$,$\nu_h\in \mathscr{M}$ how can we find $\nu_f \in \mathscr{M}$ such that $\nu_g \leq \nu_f$ and $\nu_h \leq \nu_f$.That is,If  $g$,$h$ not comparable,how collection $\mathscr{M}$ will satisfies that hypothesis of $9:13$

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The author notes that if $g$ and $h$ are simple functions less than $f$, so is $\max(g,h)$.

Then $\nu_{\max(g,h)}$ plays the role of $\mu_3$ for theorem 9.13

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: But this is valid if $g \leq h$,i.e. g,h are comparable.What happens if $g$ and $h$ are not comparable?Because in that case we can't define $max(f,g)$.So for $\nu_g$,$\nu_h \in \mathscr{M}$ who will play the role of $\mu_3$?

Comment: $\max(f,g)$ is a function defined pointwise - so $\max(f,g)(x) = \max(f(x),g(x))$. For example, $\max(x^2,x)$ is $x$ between $-1$ and $1$, and is $x^2$ everywhere else. So $\max(f,g)$ is a function which is greater than or equal to $f$ and $g$.